# lightingBitMask of SpriteKit would prevent SKAction?

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm trying to use add a lightingBitMask to the background so that I can see the effect of SKLightNode. But when I enable lightingBitMask, as shown in line 32, the action in line 55-56 would not take into effect. In other words, the "rock" stops rotating.

Here is my [code](https://github.com/hipposan/New-in-Spritekit/blob/master/NewSprite/Room.swift).

Thanks for the kindly help.

Comment: It rotates for me even when I enable line 32, but slower than before. Maybe it just suffers a so bad performance on your Mac so it "seems" not rotating for you. (If you are using an earlier MacBook Air or Mini, it might happen, I guess.)

Comment: It's probably not an issue with my macbook(the model is MacbookPro 15'' Retina). However, if I add a single background picture instead of filling the background by a loop, everything is fine. Wonder if this is the case. The performance you mention would be a factor too, and I will try it out. Thanks for you great help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is found:

If you use a simulator, the problem would occur. But if you use an iOS device, everything is fine....

I believe Xcode still has bugs with SpritKit.